# Generate date format

Tags: java

I want to generate timestamp using this Java code:

```
2016-12-25T00:00:00+0530
```

What mask should I used to get the proper result?

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new Date());
```

Comment: Well look at the pattern you've provided - does that look like the result you want? Why do you have dots in places where in your desired output there are dashes, colons or "T"? How do you expect it to know that you want the UTC offset in the output? Have you read the `SimpleDateFormat` documentation?

Comment: How I can get `T`?

Comment: Well, read the documentation and see what you can find...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the SimpleDateFormat [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) (take a look at the examples) this should give you what you want:

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+SSSS").format(new Date());
```

Edit:
If you want the last part to be the time zone offset instead of the milliseconds, you should change the pattern to:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
```

Comment: The +SSSS isn't what's wanted here - that gives milliseconds, but I believe the OP wants the UTC offset.